# Why is Nibbler's name so close to the species name of the Nibblonians?

Tags: futurama

In the episode "*[Love's Labours Lost in Space](http://theinfosphere.org/Love%27s_Labours_Lost_in_Space)*" the Planet Express crew goes to Vergon 6. There they find [Nibbler](http://theinfosphere.org/Nibbler), who was named that by Leela.

> Ahhh, I'll call him Nibbler -Leela

So why is the name Leela made up so close to their species' name "[Nibblonians](http://theinfosphere.org/Nibblonians)" if Leela just made it up on the spot?

Is it just a happy accident or is there more to it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Nibbler and the Nibblonians simply allow Leela and other humans to call them by those names for convenience. As Nibbler said in the episode ["The Day the Earth Stood Stupid"](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Stupid):

> That name is for your sake. In the time it would take to pronounce one letter of my true name, a trillion cosmoses would flair into existence and sink into eternal night.

Comment: You beat me to it, but I also wanted to add that Leela names him Nibbler after he tried to nibble Leela's boot.

Comment: @onewho It seems if they had waited to name Nibbler until after they'd seen the pairs of animals from Vergon 6 consumed, or heard of the "The feast of a Thousand Beasts" they might have instead been called "Gulper/Gulponian" or "Gobbler/Gobblonian".  ;)